# How to style standard React components styling in MUI 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to migrate my project from Material-UI v4 to MUI v5 using this [How to customize](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#3-dynamic-variation) guide from the official website but can't wrap my head how can I rewrite this component with the new guidelines:

```
...
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36)",
        display: "flex",
        height: "100%",
        position: "absolute",
        textAlign: "center",
        top: 0,
        width: "100%",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    visible: {
        visibility: "visible",
    },
    hidden: {
        visibility: "hidden",
    },
    holder: {
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
    },
}));

interface ILoaderBlockProps {
    isLoading: boolean;
    className?: string;
    testId?: string;
}

type Props = ILoaderBlockProps;

const LoaderBlock: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const classes = useStyles({});
    const { isLoading, className } = props;

    const rootClasses = clsx(
        classes.root,
        isLoading ? classes.visible : classes.hidden,
        className
    );

    return (
        <div className={rootClasses}>
            <div className={classes.holder}>
                <CircularProgress color={"primary"}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
...
```

Since `makeStyles` is deprecated and I have additional difficulties in MUI v5, I'm trying to stop using it but can't wrap my head around new styling yet.
**How could these `<div>`s be rewritten in new, v5-way since `makeStyles` is no longer an option?**
It seems the only way to do it is to introduce SCSS/CSS file with styles for `root` and `holder`.

Comment: You use the `styled` API either from `emotion` or `styled-components`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with (thanks @morganney for suggestion!):

```
...
const LoaderBlockRoot = styled("div")(() => ({
   backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36)",
   display: "flex",
   height: "100%",
   position: "absolute",
   textAlign: "center",
   top: 0,
   width: "100%",
   justifyContent: "center",
   alignItems: "center",
}));

const Holder = styled("div")(() => ({
   height: 64,
   width: 64
}));

const LoaderBlock: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => {
   const { isLoading } = props;

   return (
     <LoaderBlockRoot sx={{ visibility: isLoading ? "visible" : "hidden" }}>
        <Holder>
           <CircularProgress color={"primary"} />
        </Holder>
     </LoaderBlockRoot>
   );
};
...
```

A bit clumsy for my taste compared to `withStyles` practices though, I wonder if this could be improved.
Also, I still don't know what to do if I want to override style of component (previously, it was doable by passing `prop.className` into component).

Comment: i found this approche a pain in the a*s, for example i have a component with 10 styled div with classes & clsx. making 10 styled component add a lot of code :(

Comment: @AlainIb
To be honest, I'm still finding `useStyles/className` approach much more nicer than these styled components. Also, Typescript performance is horrible in MUI v5 (due to this and other reasons too), so I'm considering to migrate my client app from MUI v5 to something else.

Answer (score 0):

While the preferred way of styling in v5 is through `styled` or the `sx` prop, `makeStyles` still works. (Why do you say it's deprecated; it's in the v5 [docs](https://mui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook). You can even get rid of `clsx` by passing in the props directly into `useStyles` as shown in the docs example.) The code below works fine for me in v5.

As for overriding, it's still doable even with `styled` or `sx` prop. Just target the classname by using the component-slot class name convention ([docs](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-nested-component-styles))

```js
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import { CircularProgress } from '@mui/material'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.36)',
    display: 'flex',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    textAlign: 'center',
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  visible: {
    visibility: 'visible',
  },
  hidden: {
    visibility: 'hidden',
  },
  holder: {
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
  },
})

export const UseStyles: FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const classes = useStyles()

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 3000)
  }, [])

  const rootClasses = clsx(
    classes.root,
    loading ? classes.visible : classes.hidden,
  )

  return (
    <div className={rootClasses}>
      <div className={classes.holder}>
        <CircularProgress color={'primary'} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! About makeStyles deprecation - it seems that it still works for v5, but it is marked as legacy and I'm pretty sure that it will be dropped in the future.
```@mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It is deprecated in v5. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore. If you don't want to have both emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.```